# Rotating current map extent around center point in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, extents

What would be the best way to take current extent and rotate it for 90 degrees around center point and it would work for any projection.

Let's say I have a map with n-layers enabled and landscape view. Meaning I can get extent of it. How can I get extent of a rotated view (90° rotation).
Sketch of rotation:
[image: illustration of desired effect]
_

Center is fixed and should stay the same and aspect ration should be same as before.

Comment: Just use `rotate` function from `ol.View` & it should work (if I've understood your requirement) See related API doc http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#rotate

Comment: My goal is not to rotate the view, but just to get rotated extent of rotated view. It could be done by rotating, getting the extent and rotating it back, but it seems very unpractical to me.

Comment: You could maybe create a GeoJSON feature for the current extent then use [turf-transform-rotate](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-transform-rotate/README.md) to rotate it.

Comment: `map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize().slice().reverse())`  slice() is important otherwise you update the live map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
  const get_rotated_extent = (map, degrees) => {
    const view = map.getView()
    const extent = view.calculateExtent(map.getSize())
    const geom = ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(extent)
    const map_center = view.getCenter()
    const rotation_in_radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180
    geom.rotate(rotation_in_radians, map_center) 
    return geom.getExtent()
  }
  const rotated_extent = get_rotated_extent(map, 90)
```

To test it visually:

```
  const polygon_source = new ol.source.Vector()
  const polygon_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: polygon_source })
  map.addLayer(polygon_layer)
  const polygon = new ol.Feature(ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(rotated_extent))
  polygon_source.addFeature(polygon)
```